# Better way to pass server-side info to export filename?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export many images I made in one go but since everything is stored as earth engine objects, I don't know a good way to pass information into the filename portion besides using .getInfo() which significantly slows down the run-time.

```
// output
res.map(function(year){
  year.map(function(country){
    country = ee.Dictionary(country)
    
    // info for file name
    var year1 = ee.String(ee.List(country.get('year_range')).get(0)).getInfo()
    var year2 = ee.List(country.get('year_range')).get(1).getInfo()
    var month1 = ee.List(country.get('month_range')).get(0).getInfo()
    var month2 = ee.List(country.get('month_range')).get(1).getInfo()
    var country_name = country.get('country').getInfo()
    
    // export
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: country.get('image'),
      description: 'NDVIreclass'
        .concat('_', year1)
        .concat('-', year2)
        .concat('_', month1)
        .concat('-', month2)
        .concat('_', country_name),
      scale: 300,
      maxPixels: 3784216672400,
      folder : 'algorithmic-ndvi',
      region: country.get('roi')
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Please provide a complete (but minimal) example -- it's not clear what the structure of the `res` object is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, `getInfo()` is synchronous and blocks the GUI. Instead, you can use `evaluate()`, which asynchronously converts server-side objects to client-side objects.

You didn't provide a complete example, so I cannot tell if `res` is client- or server-side. I will assume it's client-side, as you don't cast `year` before mapping over it. It would have been easier to help you if you provided a more complete script.

Instead of exporting while you're mapping, you can generate an image collection containing all information needed for your export as properties, in particular the filename. Then you can `evaluate()` the list of filenames. You iterate over the client-side filenames, extract the corresponding image from the collection export it.

```
var images = ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(res.map(function(year){
  return ee.ImageCollection(year.map(function(country){
    country = ee.Dictionary(country)
    var year1 = ee.String(ee.List(country.get('year_range')).get(0))
    var year2 = ee.List(country.get('year_range')).get(1)
    var month1 = ee.List(country.get('month_range')).get(0)
    var month2 = ee.List(country.get('month_range')).get(1)
    var country_name = country.get('country')
    var filename = ee.String('NDVIreclass')
      .cat('_').cat(year1)
      .cat('-').cat(year2)
      .cat('_').cat(month1)
      .cat('-').cat(month2)
      .cat('_').cat(country_name)
    return ee.Image(country.get('image'))
      .set('filename', filename)
      .set('roi', country.get('roi'))
  }))
})).flatten())

images
  .aggregate_array('filename')
  .evaluate(function (filenames) {
    filenames.forEach(function (filename) {
      var image = images
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('filename', filename))
        .first()
      Export.image.toDrive({
        image: image,
        description: filename,
        scale: 300,
        maxPixels: 3784216672400,
        folder : 'algorithmic-ndvi',
        region: ee.Geometry(image.get('roi'))
      })
    })
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/33ae6aa07f12be2b26b24f58ad170b88

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks a lot! Sorry for not being more descriptive.